# I want to block .htm files in a directory within my WP site

Tags: security

I have a series of videos that I want to expose only to authenticated users, left over from the previous iteration of my website.  I would like each user to log in with their own password prior to accessing the video index.htm file.

Further, once they know the URL to the index file, I still want to prevent unauthorized access unless they login with a valid user account via the WP Users.

How can I control and limit access to this folder and its pages and force authentication via WP with valid accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a .htaccess file. 
Click here for more: http://engineering.oregonstate.edu/computing/web/43 .